# How to add a Project url in .nuspec file when the link itself contains element name like 'id'.

Tags: nuget, nuspec

Below is my Nuspec configuration

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package>
    <metadata>
        <id>Test x</id>
        <title>xxx</title>
        <version>1.0.0.0</version>
        <authors>xxx</authors>
        <owners>xxxx</owners>
        <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
        <description>xxx</description>
        <releaseNotes>xxx</releaseNotes>  
        <copyright>xxx</copyright>
        <projectUrl>xxx</projectUrl>
    <licenseUrl>http://<serverName>/<x>/<x>/<x>/_workitems?_a=edit&id=11136</licenseUrl>        
</package>
```

Now the nuget.exe is unable to process the licence url due to the text 'id'.
Please let me know if it is possible to make this url work. Also is there a way to add custom Elements?

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved it using CData like this:

```
http://<serverName>/<x>/<x>/<x>/_workitems?_a=edit<![CDATA[&id]]>=11136
```

Comment: Actually you could have used the XML entity for ampersand (&) which is `&amp;` so the URL would have been `http://serverName>/<x>/<x>/<x>/_workitems?_a=edit&amp;id=11136`